# Python and OpenCL issue

Tags: python, ubuntu, opencl, gpu, cpu

I'm trying to run the following script:

```
import silx
from silx.image import sift
from PIL import Image
import numpy
import scipy.ndimage
from silx.opencl import ocl, pyopencl, kernel_workgroup_size

img1 = numpy.asarray(Image.open('1.jpg'))
img2 = numpy.asarray(Image.open('2.jpg'))

alignPlan = sift.LinearAlign(img1, devicetype='GPU')
img2_aligned = alignPlan.align(img2)
```

But, get the following error which I'm not pretty sure what it means:

```
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
cl_get_gt_device(): error, unknown device: 0
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
cl_get_gt_device(): error, unknown device: 0
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
cl_get_gt_device(): error, unknown device: 0
```

**EDIT: Below is the "clinfo" output:**

```
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
cl_get_gt_device(): error, unknown device: 0
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
cl_get_gt_device(): error, unknown device: 0
Number of platforms                               3
  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 8.0.0
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer
  Platform Extensions function suffix             NV

  Platform Name                                   Clover
  Platform Vendor                                 Mesa
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 17.0.7
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA

  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 beignet 1.3 (git-8bd8c3a)
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_subgroups_short cl_khr_gl_sharing
  Platform Extensions function suffix             Intel
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
cl_get_gt_device(): error, unknown device: 0

  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     GeForce GTX 765M
  Device Vendor                                   NVIDIA Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x10de
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
  Driver Version                                  375.66
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Topology (NV)                            PCI-E, 01:00.0
  Max compute units                               4
  Max clock frequency                             862MHz
  Compute Capability (NV)                         3.0
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     1
    Supported partition types                     None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             1024x1024x64
  Max work group size                             1024
  Preferred work group size multiple              32
  Warp size (NV)                                  32
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 1 / 1       
    short                                                1 / 1       
    int                                                  1 / 1       
    long                                                 1 / 1       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 1       
    double                                               1 / 1        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  Yes
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              2094923776 (1.951GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           523730944 (499.5MiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Integrated memory (NV)                          No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       4096 bits (512 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        65536
  Global Memory cache line                        128 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             32
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            134217728 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             4096x4096x4096 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 256
    Max number of write image args                16
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               49152 (48KiB)
  Registers per block (NV)                        65536
  Max constant buffer size                        65536 (64KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     9
  Max size of kernel argument                     4352 (4.25KiB)
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    No
  Profiling timer resolution                      1000ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
    Kernel execution timeout (NV)                 Yes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution (NV)       Yes
    Number of async copy engines                  1
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer

  Platform Name                                   Clover
Number of devices                                 0

  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  NVIDIA CUDA
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Success [NV]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            Success [NV]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              <error: no devices in non-default plaforms>
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No platform

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.8
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 1.2
    NOTE:   your OpenCL library declares to support OpenCL 1.2,
        but it seems to support up to OpenCL 2.1 too.
```

Do you have an idea on how I can solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What clinfo outputs?

Comment: @Jovasa Thanks for your comment. I added the "clinfo" information in my question.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and found a solution where removing the Beignet OpenCL driver solved the problem.

```
sudo dnf remove beignet
```

Where I found my [solution](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1460400%20solution)

Comment: This is the only place where I've found "Uninstall Beignet."

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve that `DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument` error as well by removing the Beignet OpenCL driver.

This is a stopgap solution though, because I did have the Beignet driver working well alongside the Nvidia OpenCL (CUDA 9.1) driver. The problem started when I had to downgrade the Nvidia OpenCL driver to one that is based on CUDA 9.0, which I had to do in an attempt to install TensorFlow 1.8 on an Ubuntu 18.4 machine. My stuff is too new and only partially supported it seems!

Answer (score 0):

I did resolve a similar problem by removing the package
[**beignet-opencl-icd**]

```
apt-get remove beignet-opencl-icd
```